# Creating CSR programmatically

Tags: pki, x509, asn.1, csr, der

I am trying to create a CSR programmatically. I've read about ASN.1, RFC 2986, X.509.
I have also parsed several DER-encoded CSR files manually which were created using `OpenSSL`.
Everything looks clear except for a couple of things:

1. Public key part contains next bytes `8D 00 30 81 89 02 81 81` before the BIT STRING content (and after `03 81`). What is this? I noticed that all CSR files encoded with DER contain them. I didn't find anything about them in the RFC.
2. Signature part contains next unclear bytes before the signature content but after `03 81`. As I understand this part contains information about the last octet in BIT STRING (how much bites in last byte actually should be taken). But I don't understand how to decode these bytes. For example the signature could look like the following:
   `03 81 81 00 64 12 ... 24 B1 28`
   where `03h` is a BIT STRING format, `81h` length of the bit string, `64 12 ... 24 B1 28` is a signature (but it has length 80h). I don't understand the part `81 00`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your public key algorithm? RSA?

Comment: Yes, I use RSA currently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The BIT STRING in the SubjectPublicKeyInfo depends on your public key algorithm. The contents are again DER-encoded, see [RFC 3370](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3370) for possibilities.
2. If your signature looks like

   03 81 81 00 64 12 ... 24 B1 28

this is to be interpreted as follows. [DER](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf) is a TLV (Tag - Length - Value) encoding. So the first byte (octet in their parlance) represents the tag - 03 for BIT STRING as you noticed correctly.

The second byte determines the length:

> In the long form, the length octets shall consist of an initial octet and one or more subsequent octets. The initial
> octet shall be encoded as follows:

> a) bit 8 shall be one;

> b) bits 7 to 1 shall encode the number of subsequent octets in the length octets, as an unsigned binary integer
> with bit 7 as the most significant bit;

`81`has bit 8 set to one, so the remaining bits indicate the number of bytes that determine the overall length. In your case it's simply `1` byte. So the next byte is your lenght - 81 being equal to signature length of 129 bytes. So the following 129 bytes represent your value, starting with the 00.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I absolutely understand signature part. Regarding SubjectPublicKeyInfo I don't understand clearly. I use RSA algorithm for generating public key. Should I encode public key with using DER twice? I've seen RFC 3370 about it. RSA should be encoded like that:  

`RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
         modulus INTEGER, -- n
         publicExponent INTEGER } -- e`
         
But why there's used INTEGER instead of BIT STRING?

"8D 00 30 81 89 02 81 81" doesn't looks like DER format. I don't know what 8D means for example. Can you help me please?

Comment: Depending on what language you're using, there is often already a method available that lets you retrieve the DER encoding. And yes, you're right the value of the BIT STRING is again an independent (nested) DER encoding. This means if you decode the **value** of the BIT STRING, then you will get the SEQUENCE for RSAPublicKey.

Comment: That is really a great tool as it seems! Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: You write "the following 129 bytes represent your value, starting with the 00". That is not quite true: when decoding a BIT STRING, the first byte after the length indicates the number of bits that have been added as padding. In this case 0. So the value of the BIT STRING starts with "30 81" (which is recognizable as the start of the RSAPublicKey SEQUENCE).

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'programmatically', what exactly do you mean?  In code?  If so, what language are you using?  The [BouncyCastle JCE](http://www.bouncycastle.org) provider contains classes for generating a PKCS#10 request, provided you're using Java.  All you need to do is specify the necessary components (DN, public key, etc.)  There is also a .Net implementation, I believe, which may be more suitable for Microsoft environments.

Comment: I had created my own ASN.1 decoder in my iPhone project. Looks like that is the only one solution

Comment: If you're developing on the iPhone, you should be able to leverage OpenSSL.  It should have all the methods you need.  ASN.1 parsing, CSR creation, etc.